# index search returns all subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I would like to only return my embedded documents titled 'Listings', based on the text search query. Where may I be going wrong?  Creation of the index?

Here is my index:
db.Collection.ensureIndex({"Listings.Title": "text", "Listings.Description" : "text"}, {name: "Search"})

This returns the whole object, only want listings
db.AspNetUsers.runCommand("text", { search: "lawn" })

this returns just listings, but all the listings are included. Not the listings based on the search criteria e.g. 'lawn'
db.AspNetUsers.runCommand("text", { search: "lawn", project: {Listings:1}})

here is my object

```
{
  "_id" : ,
  "UserName" : "",
  "PasswordHash" : "",
  "SecurityStamp" : "",
  "Roles" : [],
  "Claims" : [],
  "Logins" : [],
  "ProfileData" : {
    "BirthDate" : new Date("3/8/1974 00:00:00"),
    "FirstName" : "",
    "LastName" : "",
    "MiddleName" : "",
    "Address" : "",
    "Address1" : ,
    "City" : "",
    "State" : "",
    "PostalCode" : "",
    "CellPhone" : "",
    "HomePhone" : "",
    "Location" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [, ]
    }
  },
  "Email" : "",
  "ConfirmationToken" : "Confirmed",
  "IsConfirmed" : true,
  "Listings" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("5331ac28a5eabf2854085df5"),
      "UserId" : ObjectId("5329b43fa5eabf0548490c27"),
      "Title" : "Lawn Chairs",
      "Description" : "lawn chairs",
      "Pictures" : ["5331ac28a5eabf2854085df6", "5331ac28a5eabf2854085df7", "5331ac28a5eabf2854085df8"],
      "Category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53273ce37dd6c71e1859ab77"),
        "Title" : "Leisure"
      }
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5331ac50a5eabf2854085df9"),
      "UserId" : ObjectId("5329b43fa5eabf0548490c27"),
      "Title" : "Lawn Ornaments",
      "Description" : "lawn ornaments troll frog gnome",
      "Pictures" : ["5331ac50a5eabf2854085dfa", "5331ac50a5eabf2854085dfb", "5331ac51a5eabf2854085dfc"],
      "Category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53273cd57dd6c71e1859ab76"),
        "Title" : "Home"
      }
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5331ac71a5eabf2854085dfd"),
      "UserId" : ObjectId("5329b43fa5eabf0548490c27"),
      "Title" : "Cell Phone",
      "Description" : "Samsung Galaxy S4",
      "Pictures" : ["5331ac71a5eabf2854085dfe", "5331ac71a5eabf2854085dff", "5331ac72a5eabf2854085e00"],
      "Category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53273cd57dd6c71e1859ab76"),
        "Title" : "Home"
      }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get just the fields you want using a [`project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/) parameter.  For getting just the `Listings` element, you could try:

```js
db.AspNetUsers.runCommand("text", {search:"lawn", project:{_id:0, Listings:1}})
```

**EDIT:**

The text command will return all documents that contain the search term.  You'll get the entire document.  If you further want to filter an array inside of the document, you can use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator, in combination with [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).  For example:

```js
db.AspNetUsers.runCommand("text", { 
     search: "lawn", 
     project: {_id:0, Listings:{$elemMatch:{ "Title": /lawn/i }}} 
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but i had already attempted that, but it returns all the listings, not the listings that only include the search criteria.

Comment: I've updated my post with an approach to limit the contents of an array.  Hope it helps.